# Error message: negative extents to matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I'm trying to make a density plot in R, using ggplot.  I am able to get the axes and the points plotted, but no density.  I am fairly unfamiliar with ggplot, as a side note.  But my z-axis is just a list of values and what shows up when I plot it is just a plot of dots.  How do I incorporate the density?

An error that pops up says there are "negative extents to matrix."  I've tried searching for this, but no luck.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(data=Denit, aes(x=Date, y=Depth, z=N2.excess)) + 
geom_point() +
stat_density2d(data=Denit, aes(x=Date, y=Depth, z=N2.excess))
```

Comment: Can you post a brief reproducible example?

Comment: You shouldn't specify `z=N2.excess` because `stat_density2d()` function calculates the z values itself. Also, you don't need to specify `data=` and `aes()` twice. Have a look at the first example on the help page: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density2d.html.